# Error running SQL Query - Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint

Tags: database, sql, magento2.2

I am trying to clear all test orders from Magento 2.2.x using this SQL query in my PHPMyAdmin but I'm getting an error.
Here's the query I am running:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`;
TRUNCATE `wishlist`;
TRUNCATE `report_event`;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `wishlist` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

The error I am getting is:

> SQL query:
>
> TRUNCATE `sales_order`
>   MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1701 - Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`store`.`downloadable_link_purchased`, CONSTRAINT `DOWNLOADABLE_LINK_PURCHASED_ORDER_ID_SALES_ORDER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `store`.`sales_order` (`entity_id`))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to truncate store table first as it is having foreign key

Answer (score 0):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE `store`;
TRUNCATE `sales_order`;
TRUNCATE `sendfriend_log`;
TRUNCATE `wishlist`;
TRUNCATE `report_event`;

ALTER TABLE `sales_order` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `sendfriend_log` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `wishlist` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
ALTER TABLE `report_event` AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

> You can try to below and also set 1 in FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS.